# Winforms using SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

```
con = new SqlConnection(cs);
con.Open();
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
current = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO CustomerDetails
(CustomerId, Date, Name, Gender, Address, Phone, Email, MobileNo,Notes)
 VALUES  ('" + txtCustomerID.Text + "','" + current + "','" + 
 txtCustomerName.Text + "','"+Gender+"','"+txtAddress.Text+"','" + txtPhone.Text 
 + "','" + txtEmail.Text+"','" + txtMobileNo.Text + "','" +txtNotes.Text + "')", 
      con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I am using this code in database my date has `datetime` datatype but when I am saving the data through form it is showing an error:

> The conversion of a varchar datatype to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

What is problem? Why is this error showing up?

Comment: Check your `Date` field if it really is a `Date/Time` data type or `varchar` as suggested by the error.

Comment: use parameters as Szymon suggested

Answer (score 1):

You should be using parameters instead of concatenating strings. Not only it will remove the problem with date formats but will also protect you from SQL injection.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO CustomerDetails
    (CustomerId, Date, Name, Gender, Address, Phone, Email, MobileNo,Notes)
     VALUES  (@CustomerId, @Date, @Email, @Mobile, @Notes)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtCustomerID.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtEmail.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtMobileNo.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Notes", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtNotes.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `getdate()` or `SYSDATETIME()` function of sql if you want to store current date.

Try This:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO CustomerDetails
(CustomerId, Date, Name, Gender, Address, Phone, Email, MobileNo,Notes)
 VALUES  ('" + txtCustomerID.Text + "',+ getdate() + ,'" + 
 txtCustomerName.Text + "','"+Gender+"','"+txtAddress.Text+"','" + txtPhone.Text 
 + "','" + txtEmail.Text+"','" + txtMobileNo.Text + "','" +txtNotes.Text + "')", 
      con);
```

**Suggestion :** your query is open to sql injection attacks so i'd suggest you to use Paramterised Queries to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating your sql string you need to append the date string, not a datetime variable. So unless you have some other reason for the current variable being a date, I would make it a string.

```
string current = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
```